# Compiler does not seem to be aware of the base type of objects in a list

Tags: c#, interface, polymorphism

I am refactoring the logging section of our code and have come across something which I just cannot wrap my head around.

We have an interface `ILogRecord` and an object call `LogDataRecord` which implements another interface `IUserLog` which in turn implements `ILogRecord`.

I have used the following style of code in lots of places and it has worked fine

```
        LogDataRecord ldr = new LogDataRecord( ... );
        ILogRecord logrecord = ldr;
```

I however cannot understand why the following piece of code is not happy

```
        logs = LogHelpers.LoadCSV( ... ));
```

`LoadCSV` return type is `List<LogDataRecord>` and logs is of type `List<ILogRecord>` I have managed to solve it by using.

```
        logs = new List<ILogRecord>(LogHelpers.LoadCSV( ... ));
```

My assumption is that the compiler cannot infer any base types of a collection but I don't understand why it can't look that deep down.

Comment: This question is asked almost everyday :) Refer the duplicate link just above your question.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I got there in the end, I had to read it a few times and read a few of Erics blogs. Possibly this is the reason why it is asked 'Everyday' because it is a very complicated topic and touches so many areas it is difficult to figure out.